# Will ViewPager Adapter's instantiateItem will be called if ViewPager.visibility is GONE?

Tags: android, user-interface, adapter, visibility, android-viewpager

I have an activity with the following layout:

```
LinearLayout  (orientation vertical)
    --> ViewPager 
    --> ListView
```

On initial load of the the activity the `ViewPager` visibility is set to be GONE though its adapter is created and set. At this point while the layout is inflated will `PagerAdapter`'s `instantiateItem()` be called or not? (because its visibility is GONE)

Answer (score 1):

I tested the flow and found that even after inflating the ViewPager view and setting the adapter for the view, if the viewpager is made GONE then instantiateItem is not called. I verified this using timer to invert the viewpager's visibility from GONE to VISIBLE after a few secs and found program flow enter the instantiateItem right immediately the visibility is changed. (perviously it didnt)